# How to view specific path inside tar.gz?

Tags: linux, compression, tar, archiving, gzip

`tar -tf file.tar.gz` let's me view inside the whole archive. How do you view a specific path without viewing the whole thing? E.g., I want to view only `/path/foo/`

Update:

This command almost works but it doesn't list the files inside `/foo/`

`tar --exclude="*/*" -tf file.tar /path/foo/`

Comment: Have you tried `tar -tf file.tar.gz /path/foo/`?

Comment: @DavidPostill that works but is it possible to only list stuff in the first level of `/path/foo/`? (e.g., `/path/foo/folder/` instead of `/path/foo/folder/subfolder/subfolder/file.txt`)

Comment: See [bash - Listing the content of a tar file or a directory only down to some level - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/listing-the-content-of-a-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. I'm almost there but I can't get to my desired results. I am doing this `tar --exclude="*/*" -tf file.tar /path/foo/` (highest voted on that page) but it only shows the folder, no files are shown (as indicated by the comment in that page). Do you know how to show the files as well? The selected answer on that page (the one using `awk`) is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: No idea, but please [edit] your question to include what code you are actually using and why it doesn't meet your needs.